# How to create API calls in React FLUX?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm new to flux. I'm struggling past 10 hrs to resolve this issues. I have created one sample todo app. Initially i want to load some data from server. But i don't know how to get that data. While i'm clicking the button that time i'm able to get the data. Please someone help me out from this problem. Because i'm trying to finish this one from long time.

My sample code,

**App.js**

```
var React  = require('react');
import * as TodoActions from "./js/Actions";
import TodoStore from "./js/stores/EventLists";

export class EventListing extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    TodoStore.on("change", this.getTodos);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    TodoStore.removeListener("change", this.getTodos);
  }

  getTodos() {
    this.setState({
      todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    });
  }

  reloadTodos() {
    TodoActions.reloadTodos();
  }

  render() {
    var List = this.state.todos.map(function(el, i){
      return <li key={i}>
        <div>{el.STA_NAME}</div>
      </li>;
    });
    return (
      <div className="listing">
        <button onClick={this.reloadTodos.bind(this)}>Reload!</button>
        <ul>
          {List}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var Events = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (<div>
               <EventListing />
        </div>);
    }
});

module.exports = Events;
```

**Store.js**

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher"

class EventLists extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.todos = [{}];
  }
  createTodo(text) {
    const id = Date.now();

    this.todos.push({
      id,
      text,
      complete: false,
    });

    this.emit("change");
  }
    getAll() {
    return this.todos;
    }
  handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "CREATE_TODO": {
        this.createTodo(action.text);
        break;
      }
      case "RECEIVE_TODOS": {
        this.todos = action.todos;
        this.emit("change");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};

const eventLists = new EventLists;
dispatcher.register(eventLists.handleActions.bind(eventLists));
export default eventLists;
```

**Action.js**

```
import dispatcher from "./dispatcher";

export function createTodo(text) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_TODO",
    text,
  });
}

export function deleteTodo(id) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "DELETE_TODO",
    id,
  });
}

export function reloadTodos() {
    var loadData;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data) {
            loadData = data;
        }.bind(this)
    });
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: "FETCH_TODOS"});
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(loadData);
        dispatcher.dispatch({type: "RECEIVE_TODOS", todos: loadData});
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Dispatcher.js**

```
import { Dispatcher } from "flux";

export default new Dispatcher;
```

Comment: just a suggestion... try redux instead of flux ...

Comment: Have you tried using axios as they did in the tutorial you followed? I followed the same one but am still experimenting with states internally without API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and the only thing that you need to change is on Action.js.

Because of the ajax call, you have to wait until the response comeback and user the dispatcher before ajar call with event `FETCH_TODOS` and on success function with event `RECEIVE_TODOS`.

Timeout is a bad idea to wait an ajax response.

```
export function reloadTodos() {
    dispatcher.dispatch({type: "FETCH_TODOS"});
    var loadData;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data) {
            loadData = data;
            dispatcher.dispatch({type: "RECEIVE_TODOS", todos: loadData});
        }
    });
}
```

**EDITTED**

Ok now I understand a little more

please add this method to Action.js

```
export function loadData() {
    dispatcher.dispatch({ type: "FETCH_TODOS" });
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            dispatcher.dispatch({ type: "RECEIVE_TODOS", todos: response });
        }
    });
}
```

and call it on your app.js on the constructor method so you can have the data initialized at the very begining

```
export class EventListing extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getTodos = this.getTodos.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
    };
    TodoActions.loadData();
  }
```

Note that because of flux you will get the data correctly when `RECEIVE_TODOS` be handled

Comment: My question is how to get the ajax data without clicking the button. Right now i'm getting the data while i'm clicking the button. @pachon-1992

Comment: did you make it work? can you choose a correct answer?

Comment: Yes. Thanks @pachon_1992.

Comment: also i got one more problem. If i'm loading image data as url (Like, http://www.google.com/sample.jpg), each time its getting reload while i'm revisiting already visited page. How to get resolve this issue?

Comment: This is another issue, can you rise a new question and explain a little more I don't understand

Comment: Posted my question here @pachon_1992. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433513/how-to-use-server-image-url-with-react-flux-store

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the data on initial load you should add a componentDidMount which calls the reloadTodos action.

```
componentDidMount() {
  TodoActions.reloadTodos();
}
```

Make sure to call this side effect in DidMount and not WillMount so the new store state will correctly trigger a re-render showing your data (it should be pretty instant)

Finally, as @pachon_1992 said you should not be using a timeout to wait for your ajax response instead you should dispatch on success